# Finding the eigenvalues of T.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have the following problem,

Let $T:M_{22} → M_{22}$ be defined by

$$
\displaystyle T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}\right) =\begin{bmatrix}
c & a+c\\
b-c & 2d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I need to find the eigenvalues of $T$.

Where do I even start with this? I know how to find eigenvalues, but it's not asking me to transform a basis here; it just wants the eigenvalues of $T$?

Do I need to use the standard basis vectors for $M_{22}$ here i.e find $$ 
[\ [T(e_{1})]_{B}\ |\ [T(e_{2})]_{B}\ [T(e_{3})]_{B}\ [T(e_{4})]_{B}\ ]
$$

Then find the eigenvalues of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a good way of doing it. So we have
$$T(e_1) = T \left( \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right] \right) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1+0 \\ 0-0 & (2)(0) \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right].$$ Now do the same for $T(e_2), T(e_3)$ and $T(e_4)$, put these entries in as columns of a matrix, then compute the eigenvalues of the matrix. If you need more details, just post a comment and I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Thank you, I did wind up solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the eigenvalues of a linear operator $T$ are the values of $\lambda$ that permit solutions to the equation $T(x) = \lambda x$. In this case, $x \in M_{2,2}$ is a 2x2 matrix, and you can use what you know about $T$ to break that into four equations:

$\begin{eqnarray} c & = & \lambda a \\
a + c & = & \lambda b \\
b - c & = & \lambda c \\
2d & = & \lambda d \end{eqnarray}$

There are any number of ways to solve this, including just treating this as a plain old eigenvector problem in $\mathbb{R}^4$.